# Issue with Spring Webclient 5: Executor not accepting a task

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm running a Spring webflux app which makes http calls to another service. Under high load (atleast this is when I see these errors), http call from webclient 5 to another service fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task` .

What could be the reason for this? Here's my HTTP call implementation.

```
public Mono<Context> doHttp(WebClient webClient, WBConfig webClientConfiguration, String data, Context ctx) {
     return getWebclient(webClient, webClientConfiguration, data, ctx)
        .headers(httpHeaders -> logHeadersAndPayload(ctx, data, httpHeaders))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Object.class)
        .publishOn(TPHelper.getSharedPool())
        .onErrorResume(getErrorHandleFunction(webClientConfiguration, ctx, taskName))
        .retryWhen(buildRetrySpec(webClientConfiguration))
        .flatMap(getResponseToContextMonoFunction(ctx, taskName, startTime));
}
```

Is this because my thread pool is overloaded? I somehow cannot figure this out and cannot simulate in my local env. This is happening on PROD env with traffic ~ 7K TPS.

EDIT - This scheduler code is just for illustration. My production code is little different and something similar to the below.

```
public class TPHelper {

// post construct create a shared TP 
private static Schedulers tp;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
  this.tp = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(100, Integer.MAX_VALUE, new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("http-threads").build(), 60);
}

public static Schedulers getSharedPool() {
  return this.tp;
}
}
```

Comment: Does the stacktrace have more info on which executor is the problematic one? Anyway that `publishOn` seems unnecessary there, that could cause issues, especially because it possibly creates new threadpool for each request as it is configured.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi This is just for illustration purpose only. my prod code has a helper class which returns the same scheduler pool and jobs are submit there. Btw, if I do not use a thread pool, it is blocking k-reactor threads. I've edited my main thread.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi I also tried without publishOn and that results in degraded performance for my app. Since there are limited k-reactor-threads. Once I published, it is faster but I see this error on traffic bursts.